# How do you send a simple email address on Android from one Intent to another Intent?

Tags: android, email, android-intent, bundle

In the other Stack Overflow questions it's a little different from what I want, and that's why it's not working. I'd like to pass a variable that stores an email address from screen to screen on Android, via Intents. I've tried several ways, including this one:

```
String emailIntoString = "testing@gmail.com";
Sender Intent:
Intent senderIntent = new Intent(FirstScreen.this, SecondScreen.class);
senderIntent.putExtra("emailIntoString", emailIntoString);
startActivity(intentEnviadora);
```

Receiver Intent:

```
Intent receiverIntent = getIntent();
Bundle receiverBundle = receiverIntent.getExtras();
String emailIntoString = receiverBundle.getString("emailIntoString");
```

But it is not working.

Please what is the code to pass a variable that stores an email address from one Intent to another Intent on Android?

**It is showing error of: "androix.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{c6b8130 VFED..CL....ID0,0-0,0#7f0900e4 app:id/email}**

Please, could someone help?

Comment: Can you please add full error log?

Comment: Please do not repost questions; edit them instead: [How to send an simple email address through Android Intents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71220949/how-to-send-an-simple-email-address-through-android-intents)

Answer (score 0):

This is right Code :

```
String emailIntoString = "testing@gmail.com";
Intent senderrIntent = new Intent(FirstScreen.this, SecondScreen.class);
senderrIntent.putExtra("emailIntoString", emailIntoString);
startActivity(senderrIntent);
```